# create apk file from command prompt

Tags: android

i want to create .apk file  from command prompt. for this i follow [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html)

and try to complete it with ant..but it is giving me error.

> taskdef class
>   com.android.ant.setuptask cannot be
>   found

can any one please help me what mistake i am doing or provide me a step by step tutorial for this.

thanks in advance...

Comment: How did you create your Android project? Did you use http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html?
Could you please paste your command line output?
Thank you

Comment: @david  i create my project in eclipse. and just want to learn to create apk from command prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass sdk.dir into ant, i.e. `ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK>`

You'll also need to specify one of the seven or so Android build targets because the default build target is 'help'.

If you just run `ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK>`, you'll get some help output, like so:

```
help:
 [echo] Android Ant Build. Available targets:
 [echo]    help:      Displays this help.
 [echo]    clean:     Removes output files created by other targets.
 [echo]    compile:   Compiles project's .java files into .class files.
 [echo]    debug:     Builds the application and signs it with a debug key.
 [echo]    release:   Builds the application. The generated apk file must be

 [echo]               signed before it is published.
 [echo]    install:   Installs/reinstalls the debug package onto a running
 [echo]               emulator or device.
 [echo]               If the application was previously installed, the
 [echo]               signatures must match.
 [echo]    uninstall: Uninstalls the application from a running emulator or
 [echo]               device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

To build the APK, you have to specify `debug` or `release`.

`ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK> debug`

Comment: please elaborate your ans so that i can get a step by step advice from you..plz do this as i have to implement this asap.

Comment: my app get successfully build. but as i  write ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK> debug  command it is giving error..Target Debug does not exist in this project....now what i have to do...plz advice me

Comment: Which command did you run successfully?and what are the errors?

Comment: @david when i go upto my projects directory.and run ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK> command it runs successfully  but as i run ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK> debug    it gives me error...Target Debug does not exist in this project.....