# Failed to find version-tag string. File must be updated

Tags: android, python, kivy, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to create apk for android using the command

```
./build.py --package org.test.hideapp --name hideapp --version 1.0 --dir /home/home/Downloads/Projects/test5/hideapp debug adb installd
```

but, I am getting the error

```
./build.py --package org.test.hideapp --name hideapp --version 1.0 --dir /home/home/Downloads/Projects/test5/hideapp debug adb installd
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
----------
build.xml: Failed to find version-tag string. File must be updated.
In order to not erase potential customizations, the file will not be automatically regenerated.
If no changes have been made to the file, delete it manually and run the command again.
If you have made customizations to the build process, the file must be manually updated.
It is recommended to:
* Copy current file to a safe location.
* Delete original file.
* Run command again to generate a new file.
* Port customizations to the new file, by looking at the new rules file
  located at <SDK>/tools/ant/build.xml
* Update file to contain
      version-tag: custom
      to prevent file from being rewritten automatically by the SDK tools.
----------
Updated file ./proguard-project.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "./build.py", line 304, in make_package
    make_pythonzip()
  File "./build.py", line 132, in make_pythonzip
    python_files = [x for x in listfiles(d) if select(x)]
  File "./build.py", line 96, in listfiles
    for item in os.listdir(d): 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/home/Downloads/python-for-android/src/private/lib/python2.7'
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229592/create-apk-file-from-command-prompt and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755109/how-to-create-apk-file-in-command-line

Comment: but those answers not related with version strings

Answer (score 1):

As much as you don't try to make something magical, but only create an `apk`, consider [buildozer](https://buildozer.io/)

So you need to do:

1. Install it with `pip install buildozer`
2. Go to your project directory and initialize it with `buildozer init`. It creates the file named `buildozer.spec` in your project directory, where you can specify the version in two ways: with `__version__` directive in your main.py (`version.regex` and `version.filename`), or explicitly in `version` directive
3. Create an apk and (optionally) deploy it on some connected device with:

   ```
   buildozer android debug deploy run
   ```

By default you will have an apk file in `bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little too late, but I just had the same problem :P
All I did was to delete my original build.xml and re-run the command, a new build.xml will be created for you automatically after the re-run.