# Kivy aplication crashes on splash screen

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, ubuntu-16.04, buildozer

I have a simple app for android written in python 2.7.12 32-bit, kivy 1.9.1 on ubuntu 16.04 64. I am able to build the app with buildozer debug deploy but the app won't start. It crashes while loading itself but stays in the 'background'. I inspected the logcat and there seems to be only one error:

build.xml: Failed to find version-tag string. File must be updated.
In order to not erase potential customizations, the file will not be automatically regenerated.
If no changes have been made to the file, delete it manually and run the command again.
If you have made customizations to the build process, the file must be manually updated.
It is recommended to:

1. Copy current file to a safe location.
2. Delete original file.
3. Run command again to generate a new file.
4. Port customizations to the new file, by looking at the new rules
   file located at /tools/ant/build.xml
5. Update file to contain version-tag: custom to prevent file from
   being rewritten automatically by the SDK tools.

I have been searching for the solution and even found some related topics but none of them seems to be related to building with buildozer. I would do what the above list instructs but i was unable to locate the /tools/ant/build.xml.

I am adding the output of terminal where app dies or at least I think it happens here:

12-25 09:58:34.762  1142  1153 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4509:org.test.localmapper:python/u0a220 for activity org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
12-25 09:58:34.920  1142  1152 I ActivityManager: Killing 4384:com.sonymobile.android.addoncamera.styleportrait/u0a67 (adj 15): empty #17
12-25 09:58:35.120  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Focus moving from null to Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
12-25 09:58:35.121  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
12-25 09:58:35.140  1142  2380 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4532:com.swiftkey.swiftkeyconfigurator/u0a178 for broadcast com.swiftkey.swiftkeyconfigurator/.PackageRemovedReceiver
12-25 09:58:35.144  1142  2380 I ActivityManager: Killing 4399:com.sonymobile.cameracommon/u0a27 (adj 15): empty #17
12-25 09:58:35.265  1142  2140 I RuntimeSkinInfo: com.sonymobile.runtimeskinning.LAF_VERSION in android blocks runtime skin from being applied, version value=2
12-25 09:58:35.265  1142  2140 I RuntimeSkinInfo: com.sonymobile.runtimeskinning.LAF_VERSION in com.android.systemui blocks runtime skin from being applied, version value=2
12-25 09:58:35.343  1142  1568 W ActivityManager: Skip forceProcessStateUpTo() to newState 11
12-25 09:58:35.367  1142  1152 I ActivityManager: Killing 3951:com.android.exchange/u0a36 (adj 15): empty #17
12-25 09:58:35.436  1142  2383 I NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-25 09:58:35.436  1142  2383 I NetworkIdentity: networkId = GNX324C50
12-25 09:58:35.448  1142  1357 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4562:com.sony.nfx.app.sfrc/u0a182 for broadcast com.sony.nfx.app.sfrc/.SocialifeUpdateReceiver
12-25 09:58:35.633  1142  1152 W ActivityManager: Skip forceProcessStateUpTo() to newState 11
12-25 09:58:35.918  1142  2144 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4584:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a132 for broadcast com.google.android.apps.photos/.backgroundsignin.BackgroundSignInBroadcastReceiver
12-25 09:58:35.920  1142  2144 I ActivityManager: Killing 4053:com.sonymobile.runtimeskinning.core/u0a185 (adj 15): empty #17
12-25 09:58:36.077  1142  2146 W ActivityManager: Skip forceProcessStateUpTo() to newState 11
12-25 09:58:36.522  1142  1569 I RuntimeSkinInfo: com.sonymobile.runtimeskinning.LAF_VERSION in android blocks runtime skin from being applied, version value=2
12-25 09:58:36.522  1142  1569 I RuntimeSkinInfo: com.sonymobile.runtimeskinning.LAF_VERSION in com.android.systemui blocks runtime skin from being applied, version value=2
12-25 09:58:36.720  1142  1152 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
12-25 09:58:36.721  1142  1152 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{56b40f7 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@8ea04f6 does not exist
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9194)
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9185)
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1209)
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:566)
12-25 09:58:36.729  1142  1568 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: null
12-25 09:58:36.731  1142  2146 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.localmapper:python (pid 4509) has died
12-25 09:58:36.731  1142  2146 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{1afe009 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity t1334}: app died, no saved state
12-25 09:58:36.742  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Focus moving from Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity} to null
12-25 09:58:36.742  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Losing focus: Window{d1f6d91 u0 org.test.localmapper/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
12-25 09:58:36.767  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Focus moving from null to Window{93f1d2e u0 com.sonyericsson.home/com.sonymobile.home.HomeActivity}
12-25 09:58:36.767  1142  1162 I WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{93f1d2e u0 com.sonyericsson.home/com.sonymobile.home.HomeActivity}
12-25 09:58:36.777  1142  2377 W InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4509 uid 10220
12-25 09:58:36.925  1142  1568 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x24000010 } from com.android.systemui (pid=14393, uid=10068) is not exported from uid 10048 due to receiver com.sonymobile.mx.android/.receivers.StopMessageReceiver
12-25 09:58:36.947  1142  2146 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4613:com.sonymobile.ree/u0a52 for broadcast com.sonymobile.ree/.service.UserPresentReceiver
12-25 09:58:37.122  1142  2382 W ActivityManager: Skip forceProcessStateUpTo() to newState 11
12-25 09:58:37.221  1142  1569 I ActivityManager: Killing 4066:com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/u0a71 (adj 15): empty #17
12-25 09:58:37.334  1142  2377 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4633:deezer.android.app/u0a200 for broadcast deezer.android.app/com.deezer.push.BootParseBroadcastReceiver
12-25 0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like version string in buildozer.spec 
Explained here, answer by eviltnan :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898873/7153696

Comment: Thank you for reply but I have the version set with method #1 in .spec so I don't think this is the reason.